# Hibernate autoconfiguring EntityManager not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have an application that runs on spring boot 3.2.1. The application has in its application.properties url, name and password for the database. Until now, the database was initialized inside of library. The parameters for initialization were passed via string values. Which does not make sense. So I decided to move the connection making part to the application. And give the library EntityManager created by Spring Boot.

But inside of the library the connection was made using Eclipselink. But now I would like to make the connection via default spring boot Hibernate. I am able to connect to database somehow, but the Hibernate EntityManager is not seeing Entities from the library. When I try to inject the EntityMager to my class via `@PersistenceContext` or `@Autowired` I get null every time. (In other application with same properties it worked)

I've tried `@EntityScan` as well as `@ComponentScan` both in main class and in configuration classes. But it failed. I've also tried moving entities inside of my application itself, that didn't work ether. This is my application.properties for the database.

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8081/name
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
# Setting custom timeout on the database connection
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=1000
```

I've used these exact setting in other applications and it worked.
Do anyone have any suggesting what could have I done wrong?

My pom.xml has these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>42.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This is my class where I'd like to send the EntityManagerFactory to my library. The MyAdapter is `@Autowired` in other class. Here when running with debugger the value of `emf` is null. When I do scheduling and run this constructor for the second time, its initialized as expected.:

```
    @Component
public class MyAdapter {

    
  /**
   * Instance of Library API
   */
  private Library libr;

  @Autowired
  private  EntityManagerFactory emf;

  /**
   * Create an instance of {@link Library} which is used for getting my data.
   *
   * @throws MyException
   */
  public MyAdapter() throws MyException {

      try {
        this.libr = new Library(emf);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MyException(e.getMessage());
      }
 
  }
  public Library getLibr() {
       return libr;
  }

}
```

Comment: Firstly: You are mixing starters and direct dependencies in your pom.xml Better stick to starters and remove others like hibernate or jakarta-persistence. Secondly remove old import statements from your entity, repository and service classes and use only the new ones provided by Spring Boot 3. Maybe you will need some code migration too. Keep asking.

Comment: A dependency in Spring (Boot) cannot be `null` if that would be the case the application wouldn't even start. Given that piece of information the only conclusion can be that you aren't using `@Autowired` on a spring managed dependency. Also your dependencies are a mess, remove `jakarta.persistence`, `jakarta.validation`, `hibernate-validator` and add `spring-boot-starter-validation`, `jakarta.persistence` is part of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already. Replace `spring-mvc` with `spring-boot-starter-web` (or remove it ifyou already have that).

Comment: @M. Deinum, @Mar-Z Thank u for your help. I think I've found the  problem, I am trying to send an EntityManagerFactory to my library that haven't been initialized yet. I am wiring the bean via `@PersistenceUnit `annotation. I've tried to change order of the auto-configuration using `@AutoConfigureOrder` and `@DependsOn`. It looks like its necessary to initialized the class I am sending EMF to my library before spring boot initializes this the EMF bean. Is there some work aroud that? Or do u any suggestion of how to correctly do this?

Comment: According to Spring docu you can annotate the configuration class in your library with @DependsOnDatabaseInitialization. Based on: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.dependencies

Comment: @Mar-Z Thank you for the advice. For some reason the value is still null. All entities are defined in the library, so I had to use `@EntityScan(basePackeges="com.example"` to ensure spring boot sees them. But I don't know how to detect, if the scan worked.

Comment: What value is null? Please share the entity class inclusive import statements. Please share the configuration class where you are "sending" EMF to. Please update your question to reflect the current state of work.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is clear for me. As you are calling the constructor of a class which is managed by Spring you will NOT get the other components autowired inside of it.

You should implement initialization in a method and annotate it with `@PostConstruct`. Like this:

```java
@Component
public class MyAdapter {
    
  /**
   * Instance of Library API
   */
  private Library libr;

  @Autowired
  private  EntityManagerFactory emf;

  /**
   * Create an instance of {@link Library} which is used for getting my data.
   *
   * @throws MyException
   */
  @PostConstruct
  public void initLibrary() throws MyException {
      try {
        this.libr = new Library(emf);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MyException(e.getMessage());
      }
  }

  public Library getLibr() {
       return libr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much <3. I was getting worried what am I doing wrong. Where would you place the `@EntityScan(basePackeges="com.example"` to work as intended. In my application there are controllers that maps some endpoints from database, but they dont work rn. There was a persistence.xml in my library but I removed it because it was using EclipseLink. Can that have any effect on that?  (I would upvote, but I am to low level for that)

Comment: You can put EntityScan in any class annotated as @Configuration. But most of us have it in the main application class.