# Spring boot RestControllers doesn't work with library containing @Entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring boot (3.2.1) application that run on java 17. I also have library that contains `@Entity` annotations. I am connection to database using spring boot default Hibernate. I am able to connect to database, but the endpoint defined in `@RestController` aren't working. I was previously initializing database from the library (passing string values) and I was using EclipseLink instead of Hibernate.

I had to newly use `@EntityScan` to get entities from the library. Previously there was persistence.xml. For some reason I am able to connect to the database inside of the spring boot but the `@RequestMapping` doesn't work. I pass the connection as `EntityManagerFactory` to my library.

I am not using repositories, I don't know if that can have any effect on the functionality.

I was discussing problems with database connection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78068194/hibernate-autoconfiguring-entitymanager-not-working-properly/78074395?noredirect=1#comment137639153_78074395).

My controller look that contains the mappings looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("${com.example.apiPrefix}/data")
public class MyController extends GodController {


  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<Integer, MyWrapper> kafkaTemplate;


  
  @GetMapping(value = "/id", produces = {"application/json"})
  @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(description = "Description...")
  public ResponseEntity<MyWrapper> getId() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {

    ResponseEntity<MyWrapper> res = null;

    .
    .
    .
    .
    return res;
  }
```

and the `GodController` looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("${com.example.apiPrefix}")
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @Info(
                title = "Hello World",
                version = "1.0",
                description = "Description"
        )
)
public class GodController {

  @Autowired
  Library libr;

  
  public SctrzController() {
  }
  
}
```

Comment: what do you mean under "@RequestMapping (located also in the app) doesn't work"

Comment: Well I was trying to say that the controllers are located in the Spring boot application and not in the library. But true is its obvious.

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved the problem. In spring boot 3 there should be http address for endpoint with backslash at the end.

I was using localhost:8080/prefix/data

It works for localhost:8080/prefix/data/

Silly mistake, hope it will help somebody one day.

Comment: Instead of posting answers, you can edit your question and append your updates.